# Include numpy and scipy in python package

Tags: python, distutils

I was wondering if there is a way to include a pure python package of numpy and scipy with my python module. I am using the scipy function loadmat for parsing data from a .mat file, and I was hoping to include scipy and numpy in a package to be distributed across multiple operating systems. My first attempt involved copying the folders from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages, and including the packages in my setup.py. However this caused the following run time error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mat2csv.py", line 9, in <module>
    import scipy.io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
    from .compat import long
ImportError: cannot import name long
```

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='mat2csv',
      version='1.2',
      description='blah',
      author='me',
      package_dir = {'' : 'src'},
      packages=['mat2csv', 'numpy', 'scipy'],
     )
```

And the code using scipy:

```
import scipy.io 

    mat_contents = scipy.io.loadmat('mydata.mat')
```

Comment: There aren't generally many good ways of doing this because the Right Thing is to just install those packages where they're needed.  That said, `virtualenv` will probably suffice for many use cases.  Unfortunately it likely won't do well spanning operating systems since these particular packages have os-specific binaries.

Answer (score 0):

you should depend on scipy and numpy rather than trying to include them, since these contain native extensions, which needs to be compiled.

If you need to distribute for several platforms, you should have a look at binary distributors of scipy such as Anaconda.

To depend on scipy/numpy your setup would look like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='mat2csv',
      version='1.2',
      description='blah',
      author='me',
      package_dir = {'' : 'src'},
      packages=['mat2csv'],
      install_requires=['numpy', 'scipy']
     )
```